Dependency life cycles are weird in Blazor WebAssembly Standalone app
I have setup an event broker which is shared between a DelegatingHandler and the AuthenticationStateProvider of the wasm app.
class LogoutBroker
{
   // For debugging purpose.
   public Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();

   public event LoggedOutHander? LoggedOut;
   public void Publish()
   {
      if(LoggedOut == null) return;
      LoggedOut.Invoke();
   }
}
delegate void LoggedOutHandler(); 

class MyProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
   readonly AuthenticationState _anonymouos = new(new());
   readonly LogoutBroker _broker;
   public MyProvider(LogoutBroker broker)
   {
       _broker = broker;
       // When the broker is registered as singleton
       // _broker.LoggedOut -= OnLoggedOut;
       _broker.LoggedOut += OnLoggedOut;
   }

void OnLoggedOut() => NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(_anonymous));

// ...

class LogoutResponseHandler(LogoutBroker broker) 
   : DelegatingHandler
{
   readonly LogoutBroker _broker = broker;
   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
      HttpRequestMessage request,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      var message = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

      if ( // check if logout has happened with message) 
         _broker.Publish();
      
      return message;
   }
}

MyProvider is a scoped service and the problem is the event invocation works only when
builder.Service.AddSingleton<LogoutBroker>();

but not when
builder.Service.AddScoped<LogoutBroker>();

At both cases, I have checked that LogoutBroker.Id has the same value in both ranges of the constructor of MyProvider and LogoutResponseHandler.SendAsync methods.
I have found that the problematic point is:
   public void Publish()
   {
      // Scoped registration matches here.
      if(LoggedOut == null) return; 

      // Singleton registration matches here.
      LoggedOut.Invoke();
   }

while I have also checked that
   public MyProvider(LogoutBroker broker)
   {
       _broker = broker;
       _broker.LoggedOut += OnLoggedOut;

       // _broker.LoggedOut is not null here.
   }

So, the event handler(MyProvider.OnLoggedOut) is never called although the event source object(LogoutResponseHandler) and the subscriber(MyProvider) shares the same broker.
As long as I am concerned, there is no difference between scoped and singleton life cycles in the context of Blazor wasm.
Anybody else can explain why I am seeing the problem?
FYI, the sample code executed at .Net 9.

Question: What's a LogoutEventBroker in LogoutResponseHandler?  Typos?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, they are. Thanks for finding. I corrected it.
